# Complex reported speech question

Tags: grammar

I had the following sentence today in my exam:

> "Would you like to come with us to a service in the Maori Church?"
>   asked my hostess. "Indeed, I would," I replied.

What would be the indirct narration of this sentence? I wrote:

> My hostess asked me if I would like to go with **them** to a service
>   in the Maori Church, to which I replied that I indeed would.

Is this correct? If not, what would be the correct version?

Comment: You would ***go*** with them -- not *come* ?

Comment: @Kris Sorry, I had written `go`, but didn't remember it. So is `go` right?

Comment: I would prefer "to which I replied that indeed I would" or even drop the "indeed" altogether.

Comment: How is this 'reported speech'? It's a written exam, right?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you proposed is correct. Alternatively, if you want to omit the us/them part, you can be more creative:

> My hostess asked me if I would like to attend a service in the Maori Church, to which I replied positively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, *them* could be unclear, since the first part of the sentence refers only to the hostess, who is one person. I like Richard's suggestion, though.